# Utopian Identification Number - REGEX pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate Utopian ID number using java regex classes, ie Pattern and Matcher.

The following are the conditions which needs to be satisfied,

1. The string must begin with between 0-3 (inclusive) lowercase alphabets.
2. Immediately following the letters, there must be a sequence of digits (0-9), The length of this segment must be between 2 and 8, both inclusive.
3. Immediately following the numbers, there must be atleast 3 uppercase letters.

Following is the code which I've written,

```
    public class Solution{public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int ntc;
        String[] str;
        try {
            ntc = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            str = new String[ntc];
            for (int i = 0; i < ntc; i++)
                str[i] = br.readLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < ntc; i++)
                if (validate(str[i]))
                    System.out.println("VALID");
                else
                    System.out.println("INVALID");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static boolean validate(String str) {
        Pattern pr = Pattern.compile("[a-z]{0,3}[0-9]{2,8}[A-Z]{3,}");
        Matcher mr = pr.matcher(str);
        return mr.find();
    }}
```

The following is the input and its respective o/p

I/P:
3

n761512618TUKEFQROSWNFWFWEQEXKPWYYCRK

rRf99

198VLHJIYVEBODQCQEGYGECOGRMQPE

O/P:

VALID

INVALID

VALID

The first testcase is Invalid as it has nine numbers instead of maximum of eight. However it says Valid.
Is there anything wrong in the Regex pattern which I've written.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use start and end anchors in your regex in-order to do an exact string match.

```
Pattern pr = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]{0,3}[0-9]{2,8}[A-Z]{3,}$");
```

Without anchors, it would match from the middle of a string also.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Matcher.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) rather than [Matcher.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), in order to match the regexp against the entire string:

```
private static boolean validate(String str) {
    Pattern pr = Pattern.compile("[a-z]{0,3}[0-9]{2,8}[A-Z]{3,}");
    Matcher mr = pr.matcher(str);
    return mr.matches();
}
```

Also, since the pattern never changes, I would move it into a constant so that it won't be recompiled every time the method is called:

```
static final Pattern UTOPIAN_ID_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("[a-z]{0,3}[0-9]{2,8}[A-Z]{3,}");

private static boolean validate(final String str) {
    Matcher mr = UTOPIAN_ID_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    return mr.matches();
}
```